# PHP MP4 Pseudo-Streaming with Flash players

Tags: php, flash, mp4, jwplayer, flowplayer

I have a PHP script that secures the MP4 file through some variables like IP address and token. It works like this:

http://www.mywebsite.com/get_file.php?file=MYFILE.mp4&token=TOKEN&IP=111.111.111.11

It works great with the HTML5 video tag, and it's seekable. However, when I test it with Flash Players, such as Flowplayer, or JW Player, the video loads, but it's not seekable. When I try to seek to some part of the video, the progress bar acts like it did seek up to that point, but the video just starts over again.

I use the smartReadFile.php to deliver the MP4 videos.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by seekable?

Comment: Is this for vstreamers.com?

Comment: To seek in a video using flash player you need upload the video on a flash media server, or download the video file.

Comment: could you provide link where you run this?

Comment: @Ben = HTML5 = http://vstreamers.com/e/1759
FLASH = http://vstreamers.com/e/1759?player=flash

Comment: You need a pseudo streaming module installed on your web server. http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430518-pseudo-streaming-in-flash

Comment: My server already has a H264 Pseudo-Streaming module. It doesn't work with the PHP delivery system.

Comment: The link here is flowplayer, not jwplayer.

Comment: It is not JWPlayer, but it is a clear example of what happens. The exact same outcome is seen on JWPlayer 6.10. However, I can't provide a link, since it's not free for commercial use.

Comment: I want a link to see how the JW Player performs.

Comment: http://www.vstreamers.com/jwplayer.php

Comment: Remove provider: 'video' and if that does not work, change start, to starttime.

Comment: Are you sure you actually have the server side pseudo streaming module installed correctly, then?

Comment: I am sure. Both JWPlayer and Flowplayer work with pseudostreaming from local accessible files, but they don't work with files secured through PHP.

Comment: Something in your php file must be altering the headers then and breaking the module.